# Executing MSBuild from Ant

Tags: ant, msbuild

I am trying to run msbuild on a Windows Server 2012 machine using Ant 1.9.7 exec task from Jenkins.

The command line I am attempting to recreate is:

```
msbuild solution.sln /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration:Release
```

My latest attempt at the exec task looks something like:

```
<property name="platformParameter" value='/p:Platform="Any CPU"' />
<echo message="platformParameter = ${platformParameter}" />

<exec executable="msbuild" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="solution.sln" />
    <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release" />
    <arg value="${platformParameter}" />
</exec>
```

The environment is correct so msbuild is available.  The output from the above that I am getting is:

```
[echo] platformParameter = /p:Platform="Any CPU"
[exec] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.40629.0
[exec] [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34014]
[exec] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[exec] 
[exec] MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
[exec] Switch: CPU
```

The echo output shows that the platformParameter correctly contains what I want with double speech marks around Any CPU as required by msbuild.  Using single speech marks, no speech marks or AnyCPU when attempting to build a solution does not work.  I believe that if I were building a project rather than solution I would be able to use AnyCPU instead of "Any CPU" for the platform.

The error appears to be that msbuild is not seeing the Platform parameter correctly formed and therefore probably thinks I'm doing:

```
msbuild solution.sln /p:Platform=Any CPU /p:Configuration:Release
```

where it thinks CPU is a second project/solution.

I've tried a few different things to try and get this argument containing double speech marks to msbuild via the exec task (e.g. using "e; in place of the double speech marks), usually with the same result as shown above.

Can anyone suggest the correct/a working method to get the Platform parameter into an arg for the exec task to run to msbuild? 
i.e. How define an arg containing a double speech mark delimited element to a exec task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried removing the space so your platform says `AnyCPU`?

Comment: Additionally try specifying at a target parameter as well `/t:Build`

Comment: @JamesReed - Yes, as per my opening text, using AnyCPU without a space only works if you are building against a project file rather than a solution - an inconsistency that Microsoft have said they have no intention of addressing

Comment: @Tuffwer - I do not think adding more msbuild parameters will help as one of the existing parameters is not being correctly received by msbuild.  Once I have an operational Platform="Any CPU" parameter I may well add the appropriate build option to force a full rebuild but that is not the focus of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

It appears I was attempting to pre-empt/solve something that did not need solving.

From a windows command prompt to get MSBuild to work I needed to do:

```
msbuild solution.sln /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration:Release
```

as stated in my question.

For the ant exec task arguments, the Platform parameter appears to work perfectly fine if I do:

```
<exec executable="msbuild" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="solution.sln" />
    <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release" />
    <arg value="/p:Platform=Any CPU" />
</exec>
```